# How to resolve "all recodings should be formula" error in R

Tags: r, dplyr, recode

I've been trying to recode numeric data, but I keep getting an error message I haven't seen anywhere previously or on Stack Overflow.

Let's say this is our dataframe

```
age <- c(11, 27, 35, 42, 89)
dfage <- as.data.frame(age)
```

Then I try and recode to different numbers

```
dfage %>%
  mutate(age = recode(age, `11` = 1L, `35` = 2L))
```

But I receive the error message

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
'recode': all recodings should be formula but: 1L
```

Even if I try a different type of recode

```
dfage %>%
  mutate(age = recode(age, `11` = "a", `35` = "b"))
```

I still get an error.

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  'recode': all recodings should be formula but: "a"
```

Any ideas about what the problem could be and how to fix it?

Comment: Please indicate which packages you have loaded. There are several packages containing `recode` functions. Maybe share the output of `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: Perhaps, use `dplyr::recode` ?

Comment: Does the error persist if you do ``dfage %>%
  mutate(age = dplyr::recode(age, `11` = 1L, `35` = 2L))``?

Comment: Thank you all! The problem was solved after using dplyr::recode. I had recently loaded expss package which contains expss::recode. I believe this was the problem.